# React CSSTransition "Type {number} not assignable to type boolean"

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to the React CSS Transition Group, but I thought I would give it a little try, just working with an example from their own website. So basically what I have is this:

REACT:

```
import React, { memo, useState } from "react";

import "./style.styles.scss";
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group'

const App= ( ) => {

    const initialCount = 0
    const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount)

    const components = [
        <CSSTransition in={count} timeout={200} classNames="my-node">
        <div className="box">
            <div>DIV1</div>
            <div className="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Next</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </CSSTransition>,
        <CSSTransition in={count} timeout={2000} classNames="my-node">
        <div className="box">
            <div>DIV2</div>
            <div className="button" onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>
                Prev</div>
            </div>
            <div className="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Next</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </CSSTransition>
    ]

    return (

        <div>
            {components[count]}
        </div>
    );
};

export default memo(App);
```

CSS:

```
.my-node-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2000ms;
}

.my-node-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2000ms;
}

.my-node-exit {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2000ms;
}

.my-node-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2000ms;
}
```

So I am trying to have two divs, with different content, and the initial state is to open/show the first div `DIV1`, and then when "Next" is clicked I go to the next div `DIV2`, which I can switch between through the count state. Now, that is working, but they just show up, and disappear with no animation. I then saw this CSSTransition for React, which seemed to be able to do this animation stuff quite easily. But I am kind of stuck on my example above (which is taken from their website). It's obvious that the problem is with the `in` expression in the CSSTransition, which says "Type {number} not assignable to type boolean". So that's probably because it expected a true/false statement. So my question is: How do I convert this into a "count". I am thinking I might need some kind of if-statement saying something like: "if count == 0 then". But as I am new to React, I am not quite sure how this works in this case ?

Comment: if your goal is for the `in` prop to be truthy for either 0 or 1, then you can just put that expression in the curly brackets: `in={ count === 0 }`

Comment: The idea was actually to have more than one div (let's say 4), so the count gets higher for each click of a button, or lower if "Prev" is clicked. And then it changes, and the animation should occur when doing so.

Comment: Well, the same would work for `count === 1` and so on. I'm not familiar with that library, but looking at your code again `{components[count]}` effectively unmounts any component that does not have the `count` index. IIUC whatever animation is supposed to happen would be prevented by exactly that.

Comment: Just in case I did not make myself clear, IIUC the `CSSTransition` all need to be rendered inside your `return`, but would not show up unless `in={true}`. Your buttons consequently cannot be children of them.

Comment: So my buttons has to be "created" inside the return ?

Comment: It all needs to be rendered. Look at the [example from the docs](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition). The `CSSTransition` component - and all its children - is not visible until `showMessage` evaluates to true. This applies to any such component, even if you have multiple like you intend to. Only the one(s) where `in` has a truthy value will transition in. Others will transition out. You need to render your buttons outside of them, just like in this example, otherwise they transition in and out as well. You need only one "next" and one "previous" button each.